# JRuby on rails encoding error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, jruby, jrubyonrails

Yesterday I tried to switch from MRI to JRuby and I believe that i got all the gems right.

I am using Mongoid and not ActiveRecord so no switching of gem necessary there I think.

The error I get is:

```
incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
```

The Full trace can be shown here: https://gist.github.com/1305847

And my Gemfile can be shown here: https://gist.github.com/1305882

Does anyone have a clue to what the solution might be?

Comment: Please post the output of both `ruby -v` and `jruby -v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there was a problem with jruby 1.6.4.
After upgrading to 1.6.5 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try with running JRuby in 1.9 mode:

```
$ jruby --1.9 rails s
```

You can also `$ export JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9`

Comment: What is in here? `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:12`

Comment: There is an render partial there.
Which renders some UTF-8 characters including `åäö`

This is not an error with MRI but just JRuby. Ive read some bug tickets and it seems to be just an JRuby bound error